# Highlighting text within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, text, highlight

I'm currently developing a small site (using HTML, Javascript and PHP) and I have a page in which I have built an iframe.
Now I want to highlight an given text (be it hardcoded, albeit given using a textbox) within the iframe, every time the pages loads (so with an onload="").

I've searched Google for about an hour and didn't find something that worked. 
Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Regards

Comment: Is the iframe content served up by you?

Comment: Highlight what, and how? Selecting it? Changing the background colour?

Comment: No, it's an include of an external site.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't modify the content of the external page in the iframe, since it doesn't belong to you.

If you use jQuery and try to change the background color of an element in the iframe

```
$('#myIframe').contents().find('#element').css('background-color', 'red');
```

you'll get a JS error.

You have to find a workaround; one would be to include in the iframe a server-side page that reads and output the external page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are wanting to achieve the highlighting using JavaScript. To manipulate the contents of the iFrame with JS you'll want to dynamically load the iFrame in the JavaScript and then can do what you like with it.